# Python: MySQLdb connection MAMP database unknown

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MAMP server database which has all the privileges for all users. I am trying to connect to the database through a python file. It shows following error:

```
File "mymodule.py", line 3, in <module>
    con = mdb.connect('localhost','root','root','network')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'network'")
```

My code is

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost','root','root','network')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO trial(count) values(100)")
```

It is not a problem with just this database. Its the problem with all databases. I cannot connect to any of it. Please guide.

Comment: Try init connection using keywords instead of arguments

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am really new to python

Comment: It doesn't work still. I have an error of unknown database

Comment: Are you sure that your database exist? If you run from command line `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -proot network` - what does it shows?

Comment: It works fine. I had tried this